# Add StatusBar Like View in App?

Tags: ios, statusbar

In my app I want to add a view much like the status bar, always onscreen at the top of each of my view controllers, displaying application wide data.

I really have no clue how I might achieve this so any suggestions would be really helpful. I;m sure someone must have chased this idea at some point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're willing to do is fairly straightforward since iOS 5 using view controller containment, it allows you to embed child view controllers in a parent view controller.
In your case I would create a custom container view controller with two subviews: the content view and the statusbar-like view. The content view should display your current root view controller by adding it as a child view controller to your container view controller and adding its view as a subview to the content view. The statusbar-like view can then be used to display information that will be visible everywhere in your app.

You might want to read this documentation for further details:
[Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom view and add it as a subview to your keyWindow. This way it will always be visible. Another option is if you have tab bar controller or a navigation controller as your root view controller, then you can add that view as a subview to their respective view and it will always be visible.